# Unable to insert data into GrapheneDB using curl from PHP

Tags: php, curl, neo4j, graphenedb

I am using GrapheneDB and I tried re-using the code which I used to use it to connect to Neo4J server from AWS server. But It is not inserting data into GrapheneDB and I have no idea what is wrong here. Previously, I used used `localhost:7474` but now I'm using the following URL. How can I get it to work?

```
$http="http://username:password@hobby-1312.dbs.graphenedb.com:2789/db/data/cypher/";
$data =' MERGE (a:User {name:"name",id:"id" }) ';
$data = array("query" =>$data);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($http);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: What is the response you are getting from Neo4j? Can you add the http response code and the response body?

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: I have added :
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($result, $header_size);  And I get 0 as the response

Answer (score 0):

I'm Judit from GrapheneDB. The code you have shared should work. Are you maybe behind a restrictive firewall? Our instances run on non-standard ports and some firewalls block access.